# Dell XPS 1710 suspend wakeup issue with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: suspend, dell, xps, wakeup

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my Dell XPS 1710 with 4 GB RAM.

It is a Core Duo T7200 2ghz processor with a (former) high end Nvidia 7950 GTX video card.

It is the only OS that allows to make work last versions of Firefox, Chrome and Edge on that computer.

I use only the default compatibility drivers installed with Ubuntu, and it works well.

The only issue I have is: it does not wake up from suspend. It does power on, I see HDD led working, but not WIFI, and the screen remains black.

I searched into energy options, look at BIOS energy settings (found nothing, there is no deep sleep option).

I search for any help resolving this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Ok I just added the precise version : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I also installed all updates, so it is completly up-to-date.

Comment: You may also benefit from stating you kernel stack choice you made (*installation media will dictate this*).  If you're using the 5.15 kernel you're using the GA kernel stack (at 22.04.2), if using the 5.19 kernel you're using the HWE kernel stack (HWE is the default for Ubuntu Desktop installs, but not Server or *flavor* installs if 22.04/22.04.1 media was used).  If you have both 5.15 & 5.19 installed; I'd suggest trying both and see if it's the same (as if 5.15 works for example; switching to GA stack is easy). Your CPU is old, & older hardware often does better with older stacks in my exp.